# Ant based Scala compiler is deprecated

Tags: scala, gradle

Running `Gradle build` shows warnings and i dont know how to change the scala compiler so that it is not ant based.

Anyone know how to stop these warnings?

```
useAnt has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0. The Ant-Based Scala compiler is deprecated, please see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html.
fork has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0. The fork option for the scala compiler is deprecated, please see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html.
```

The links in the warnings don't help.

Comment: Have you read the error message? Maybe followed the [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html) that came with it? There should be enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: I get this warning on basic HelloWorld project with only scala plugin, mavenCentral as a repo, and scala 2.11+ as a dependency.  I later added zinc as an explicit dependency and watched gradle download zinc.  Still is using ant and gives warnings.

Comment: @SaschaKolberg , I also have this problem, followed the link and found zero useful information. It talks about zinc compiler but doesn't say what to do with it and how to get rid of the message. Did I overlook something?

Comment: @cheezsteak shame on me! It seems, it's a side effect of [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/65e762acdc15eaf942377d1fa95cec3021b95e20) change in gradle preparing the migration to zink scala compiler. So as a result (as far as I can see)  the message will always show up and can be safely ignored for now.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid for the message now?

Answer (score 1):

Using a recent version of the plugin won't show these warnings.